# I need a hardware or software solution for guaranteeing a particular video output resolution and refresh rate on a computer running MS Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, hdmi, edid

I'm looking for a solution to reliable fixed output resolution and refresh from a Windows 7 PC.

Ideally a hardware solution, i.e. a particular motherboard (maybe with LVDS) or a BIOS or graphics BIOS setting.

If this isn't possible then a software solution in Windows 7 that allows me to set a display resolution and refresh that will NEVER be changed or reset automatically, no matter what display is plugged in, or even if no display is connected.

Thanks
Louis

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. Unfortunately, video modes & resolutions change quite often between bootup and final OS load. Various BIOS software, EFI, Windows (or other OS) startup, and final Windows load often have different video modes & resolutions. Additionally, any time you do video driver updates, the video mode will also change briefly.

Once you get through bootup, it is possible to do what you describe. You can easily set the computer to never sleep / shutdown / reboot after booting (although bear in mind that you may have to reboot from time-to-time if there are updates).

Question is, is it ok for whatever your application that the video modes to change only during the bootup process?

Comment: Thanks.  As a work around, if windows always booted up to the same res and refresh i'd be in a better place than I am now, so I'd love to hear how to do this.  BUT  I have been thinking, surely laptops don't change display mode as they boot up?  There must be some way of mimicking the same behaviour on a Mini ITX PC (which is what i'm using). Thanks.  Louis

Comment: Once you configure windows to operate at a given resolution and refresh rate, it will always boot to that configuration. You should not have any problems.

Comment: Joshua, I appreciate your optimism but the problem I have is that I don't necessarily know what device is going to be plugged into this machine... i.e. I'd like to give out the same res and refresh regardless.  Thanks.  L

Comment: Each time you connect a new device and configure the display with that device, Windows will remember that configuration. I can verify that this works with newer displays, many TV's, and many projectors. I have a laptop that I often swap between an Apple Cinema Display, a Dell U2711 monitor, a projector with 1280x720, the laptop itself. Windows remembers the settings for each device.

Comment: Agreed.  But there are situations where you want to force a particular resolution and refresh, either to a new device or because we've changed out setup.  We want to enforce this.  Thanks.  L